# How to add enable flag for Flight Recorder in Maven project?

Tags: maven, flags, jmc, jfr

I'm just about start using **Java Mission Control 5.3.0**.

I have added **-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder** into my web-app's jetty.template.

Then I start the web-app with **mvn jetty:run**.

But while I was starting **Flight Recorder** I got the problem occurred pop-up as below.

> ```
> 'Start Flight Recording.. (Last attempt failed)' have encountered a problem.Commercial features are not enabled. In JDK7u4 and above,the JVM must be started with -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder .
> ```

And I also try adding the flags as below into **pom.xml** but it doesn't work.

```
<jvmArgs>
    <jvmArg>-Xmx128m</jvmArg>
    <jvmArg>-Xms128m</jvmArg>
    <jvmArg>-XX:MaxPermSize=512m</jvmArg>
    <jvmArg>-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures</jvmArg>
    <jvmArg>-XX:+FlightRecorder</jvmArg>
    <jvmArg>-XX:StartFlightRecording=duration=160s,delay=20s,settings=profile,filename=target/recording.jfr</jvmArg>
</jvmArgs>
```

What should I do for enable Flight Recorder on my web-app?

Comment: I'm facing similar issue a maven project for wildfly server, did you ever resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

That configuration should be added to the running VM of Jetty so I'd try this:

```
mvn jetty:run -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder
```

I could not test this, and I work most on Tomcat, but I think this could help you

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer by using below.

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="$MAVEN_OPTS -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `jcmd` command from jdk, then could enable JFR via:

`jcmd 31118 VM.unlock_commercial_features`

Then use JFR.

e.g

`jcmd 31118 JFR.start name=a`

Answer (score 1):

After some tests, I'll add something that could help someone else :

This is the JVM (Azul Zulu) I am using for my tests :

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_272"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.50.0.21-CA-linux64) (build 1.8.0_272-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.50.0.21-CA-linux64) (build 25.272-b17, mixed mode)
```

I created in the top of the project a file :

```
.mvn/jvm.config
```

That contains only one instruction :

```
-XX:StartFlightRecording=filename=build.jfr
```

Then, do whatever mvn goal you want to do and look for the build.jfr command you want.

Zulu's JVM has flight record enabled by default, so you this is one step less to worry.

It is important to mention that, in my case I had several JVM's installed in my machine and the mvn command uses JAVA_HOME variable, so make sure it is pointing to the right jvm.