# How to import lib for JMX and Java mission Control?

Tags: java, jmx, jmc, jfr

Two questions I am having are:

1. How to Import lib for jmx(i can't import it)?
2. Can we access Java Mission Control using Code? (like I can 
   see the visualisation of my problem but I want to fetch it 
   into my IDE using code), is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add enable flag for Flight Recorder in Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518834/how-to-add-enable-flag-for-flight-recorder-in-maven-project)

Comment: Which IDE are you using? which sort of project are you using? If you are using maven, see the duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518834/how-to-add-enable-flag-for-flight-recorder-in-maven-project otherwise, download the .jar file and put in the classpath/lib folder of your project

Comment: To use Java Mission Control libraries in your code, this might be useful: http://hirt.se/blog/?p=920

Comment: if there is any .jar file for it  , can anyone give me a link here? i can't find it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Oracle JDK 9+ or OpenJDK 11+, you can access the data in a JFR file using the Flight Recorder API.

For example, to print all the events:

```
import jdk.jfr.consumer.*;

try (RecordingFile r = new RecordingFile(Path.of("recording.jfr"))) {
 while (r.hasMoreEvents()) {
   System.out.println(r.readEvent());
 }
}
```

For more information about the API:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.jfr/jdk/jfr/consumer/package-summary.html

Comment: can we do the same thing without using Jfr and Jmc?

Comment: If you want to access Flight recorder data, you need a parser that can read the files.There are two parsers, one that comes with JDK (jdk.jfr.consumer.*) and one that ships with JMC. You also changed your question to be about JMX. which there is also an API for in the JDK (java.management.*)

Comment: no need to change the question , that was exactly what i was looking for, this is just curiosity Question .